# EF6 CodeFirst ForeignKey attribute mapping not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I have a many-to-1 situation where an Employee can serve many Customers and each Customer is served by 1 Employee. In the Customer class I map SupportRep to EmployeeId using the ForeignKey attribute and it gives me an error.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    ...

    public int? SupportRepId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee SupportRep { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    ...

    [ForeignKey("SupportRepId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Error: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SupportRep' on type 'SqlLiteChinook.
>   Customer' is not valid. The foreign key name 'EmployeeId' was not found on the d
>   ependent type 'SqlLiteChinook.Customer'. The Name value should be a comma separa
>   ted list of foreign key property names.

However, if I change EmployeeId to SupportRepId in the Customer class it works.

Shouldn't the foreign key in the Customer class point to EmployeeId of Employee class?

Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing things up a bit. The `[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]` in your `Customer` class has to say which property of that class is the foreign key to `Employee`. The attribute doesn't go looking for the foreign key in the `Employee` class.

Your second mistake is declaring a foreign key on the `ICollection<Customer>`. Since you have a one-to-many relationship, your collection can't point to *one* customer, it has a relation to multiple ones. So your customer needs to have the foreign key to employee (each customer 'points' to one employee) but employee can't contain a foreign key to customer.

```
public class Customer
{
  [Key]
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  ...
  public int? SupportRepId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("SupportRepId")]
  public virtual Employee SupportRep { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  [Key]
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    ...

    public int? SupportRepId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SupportRepId")]
    public virtual Employee SupportRep { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```